# Length of $4y=x^2+4$ inside circle $x^2+y^2 \leq8$.

Tags: analysis

$$4y=x^2+4 , x^2+y^2 \leq8$$
I am looking for the length of the parabola inside the circle. I know its with integral  in interval $(-2 , 2)$ but i don't know how to do it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use parametric equations for parabola and let $x=2t$, then $y=t^2+1$ so substitute in integral 
$$\ell=\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}\,dt$$

Answer (score 1):

The length it's the integral

$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt {1+\frac {x^2}{4}} dx$$

Now substitute $x = 2 \sinh t $, $dx = 2 \cosh t \; dt $, $t_1 = arcsinh (-1)$, $t_2 = arcsinh (1)$

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} 2 \cosh t \sqrt {1 + \sinh^2 t} \;  dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} 2  \cosh^2t \; dt = \left[ t - \cosh t \; \sinh t \right]_{t_1}^{t_2} =\left[ arcsinh x - x \sqrt{1 + x^2} \right]_{-2}^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image: figure]

The two points of intersection are $(2,2)$ and $(-2,2)$. The required length is then obtained by computing the line integral :
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{(1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2)} \ dx = \int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{4}} \ dx$$